# Jquery Multi-Select For very large number of options

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-select2

Consider the case where the user have to select multiple values from a list of thousands values. The closest i got to a usable tool is the http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

The main problem is due to the large number of data from which the user have to select. 
The approach that i currently use is that the user have to enter the first character in the text box and then all the values starting with the first character shall be displayed for multiple selection.(thus filtering to a sizable list of values)

The problem is that even then the number of values are so large that it takes a 5-15 seconds to reload the multi-select options. But once the values are loaded, the javascript filtering handles the rest, as the user enters succeding characters.

Any suggestion on any other way to tackle this situation????

Comment: I think that posting some (HTMl, JavaScript/jQuery) code along with your situation would help us troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a multiselect box that is pre-populated use [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to filter the list server side and only return matches to the client (similar to the way the tag selection works on StackOverflow).

There is a good example of selecting multiple values here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

You can then save the results of the selections in the same way you would process a multiselect.

To implement a hybrid approach where the first letter fetches terms from the server and then afterwards filters from those results, you could use the following (please note that this is completely untested):

Add a global var to hold your results

```
var results_cache = [];
```

Use a hybrid source in your `autocomplete`

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    // get the first letter of your search term
    var letter = request.term.substring(0,1);
    // check to see if we already have results for this letter
    if (!results_cache[letter]){
        // no results, fetch via AJAX
        $.getJSON( "search.php", { term: request.term }, 
            function(data){ 
                // cache results
                results_cache[letter] = data;
                // filter results (in case we have more than just 1 character in the term)
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term));
            }
        );
    } else {
        // we already have data for this letter, just filter the results from the cache
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(results_cache[letter], request.term));
    }
},
search: function() {
    // make sure we have at least 1 character for the term
    if (!this.value) return;
    var term = this.value;
},
```

Comment: Are you sure jQueryUI Autocomplete filters server side? What has lead you to believe that?

Comment: @DougieBear I meant to use an AJAX `source:` to load your data, which can then be filtered server side. I have implemented this in the past.

Comment: Ok, i just checked, there is a multiple values selection autocomplete option also. pretty cool, but isn't the multi-select option mentioned earlier better, where with just one ajax search for the first letter entered, we can get the pre-populated list and then add as amany values from the result in a single click rather than entering each of them separately. It would be faster.

Comment: @kapil that would definitely be an option, but you would need to implement a hybrid of the two yourself, i'll put an example in my answer.

Comment: @kapil updated with an example, untested but hopefully enough to infer the intent.

Comment: @ doublesharp i get the idea... + using an auto-complete, instead of multi-select, will also keep the design simple and short. thanks....

Comment: @kapil Great... can be tweaked for performance should your number of results change too, for example only showing results once X number of characters have been entered (yet still pulling from the server for the first letter), or making a request to the server for X characters instead of just the first (if you end up with more data, this might make it more responsive)

Comment: @doublesharp Yepp... But just one doubt. If say the response data is large and we keep it in a javascript global variable for multiple input enteries, how much data can be stored in the variable... I know it is out of context, but just i never stored such large data in a javascript variable...

Comment: @kapil - you were originally storing them all in a `<select>` and then filtering with javascript, so probably not *too* large, but if you're worried about it you can always omit the caching part and always fetch just the first letter, or only keep `N` results cached, though this would require that you add additional functionality to just clear the array of the oldest data, or whatever scheme you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The following were helpful:

**First,** filter the values based on certain input parameters, before selecting the final large size input.
**Secondly,** increasing the limit from one character to multiple before the jquery select values are loaded. This shall limit the number of values further, but the user shall have to be aware of the multiple character input limit

But http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/ still feels the best avaliable option out there.